# Not finding local data files saved in my application

Tags: android

The process seemed quite simplistic at first, but there must be something that I am missing going forward with this task.  There was a settings file that I wanted to create local to my application for storing a whole bunch of data (not preference worthy).  I ended up saving the file with the following code snippet.

```
protected File createSettingsFileLocation(String fileNameF)
{   
    File directoryFile = context_.getDir("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File settingsFile;

    settingsFile = new File(directoryFile, fileNameF);

    if (!settingsFile.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            settingsFile.createNewFile();
        } catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(MyConstants.LOG_TAG, "Could not create the file as intended within internal storage.");
            return null;
        }   
    }

    return settingsFile;
}
```

and then proceeded to retrieve the file later by looking for it locally with the following code snippets.

```
public String getCurrentFileContainingSettings()
{
    List<String >settingFilesInFolder = getLocalStorageFileNames();

    if (settingFilesInFolder == null || settingFilesInFolder.isEmpty()) 
    {
        return null;
    }    

    String pathToCurrentSettingsFile = settingFilesInFolder.get(0);

    return pathToCurrentSettingsFile;
}

protected List<String> getLocalStorageFileNames()
{
    return Arrays.asList(context_.fileList());
}
```

However, the `settingFilesInFolder` always returns no entries, so I get null back from the `getCurrentFileContainingSettings()`.  As what I could see from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) it seems as thought I was doing it right.  But, I must be missing something, so I was hoping that someone could point something out to me.  I could potentially hard-code the file name once it has been created within the system in a preference file for access later the first time that the settings are created, but I shouldn't have to do something like that I would think.

Comment: "However, the settingFilesInFolder always returns no entries" -- since you have not published your implementation of `settingFilesInFolder()`, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's just a list of strings variable, not a method.  Sorry if the variable name threw you off.  Should have all the methods related to this available above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fileList()` only looks in `getFilesDir()`, not in its subdirectories, such as the one you created via `getDir()`. Use standard Java file I/O (e.g., [`list()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#list%28%29)) instead.

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a shot.  Kind of an oddity that they provide an API to put and retrieve, including putting it into a personal folder, but not provide the extra API parameter for retrieving out of the directory that you can create with the API.

Comment: @JaySnayder: That's why I largely stick to `getFilesDir()` and standard Java file I/O. :-)